# Recoding ShuffleSplit from sklearn

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am fairly new to Machine Learning and currently I am going through the book 'Hands-on
Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & TensorFlow' from O'Reilly.
In exercise 8 of chapter 6 ([here is the full exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBVHD.png)) the goal is to fit a random forest classifier on the training set of the moons dataset. For that it is asked to generate 1,000 subsets of the training, each containing 100 instances selected randomly. This can be done by means of the ShuffleSplit method from scikit learn. When I do so I also get nice results. However, I tried to implement the ShuffleSplit method myself but something goes wrong and I can't figure out what it is.

First I do a small Grid Search to find a good parameter setting for fitting one single decision tree:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=10000, noise=0.4)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)


param_dic = {'max_leaf_nodes': list(range(2, 100)),
            'min_samples_split': [2,3,4]}


dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc_grid = GridSearchCV(dtc, param_dic, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
dtc_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_params = dtc_grid.best_params_
dtc.set_params(**best_params)
dtc.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = dtc.predict(X_train)
print(f'Accuracy Score on Train Set: {accuracy_score(y_train, predictions)}')
predictions = dtc.predict(X_test)
print(f'Accuracy Score on Test Set: {accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)}')
# Accuracy Score on Train Set: 0.855875
# Accuracy Score on Test Set: 0.8525
```

Now I want to create 1000 random subsets of the training set of size 100. For that I create the following class:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
import random 

class CreateSubsets(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, n_sets, set_size):
        self.n_sets = n_sets
        self.set_size = set_size
        
    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        self.new_sets = {}
        for set_i in range(self.n_sets):
            idx = random.choices(range(len(X)), k=self.set_size) 
            X_new, y_new= X[idx], y[idx]
            self.new_sets[set_i] = (X_new, y_new)
        return self.new_sets    
 
n_sets, set_size = 1000, 100
cs = CreateSubsets(n_sets, set_size)
new_sets = cs.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
```

Next I fit the decision tree classifier with the optimal hyperparameter setting found by GridSearchCV on each of the small random datasets and predict labels of the test set observations. Those predictions are saved in `tree_predictions` for later purpose. Finally, the accuracy score is predicted for each fit and those values are averaged.

```
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc.set_params(**best_params)
tree_predictions = np.zeros((n_sets, len(X_test)))
accuracy_scores = []
for set_i in range(n_sets):
    X_train_new, y_train_new = new_sets[set_i][0], new_sets[set_i][1]
    dtc.fit(X_train_new, y_train_new)
    predictions = dtc.predict(X_test)
    tree_predictions[set_i,:] = predictions
    accuracy_scores.append(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))

print(f' Average performance of Decision Tree Classifier with optimal Hyperparameter Setting,\n fitted on smaller subsets: {np.mean(accuracy_scores)}')    
# Average performance of Decision Tree Classifier with optimal Hyperparameter Settings, fitted on smaller subsets: 0.4941225
```

As a final step, for each instance of the test set I do a majority vote over the predictions (by taking the median over the predictions per test observation). Computing the accuracy score on those majority predictions should be higher than the average prediction score prior.

```
from scipy.stats import mode
predictions = mode(tree_predictions, axis=0)
accuracy_score(y_test, predictions[0].reshape(-1))
#0.403
```

Something certainly goes wrong with the class CreateSubsets, but I can't figure out what it is. If I use ShuffleSplit from sklearn like this instead, the random forest classifier performs well:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit

n_sets, set_size = 1000, 100
new_sets = []

rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=n_sets, test_size=len(X_train) - set_size)
for mini_train_index, mini_test_index in rs.split(X_train):
    X_mini_train = X_train[mini_train_index]
    y_mini_train = y_train[mini_train_index]
    new_sets.append((X_mini_train, y_mini_train))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should focus on the part of the code you have a problem with. See [MRE]. Here your class seems wrong as you do not init the classes you inherit from. You should also post the error messages your get.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).